# Fill values in a numpy array given a condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Currently I have an array as follows:

```
myArray = np.array(
    [[ 976.77 ,  152.95 ,  105.62 ,   53.44 ,   0 ],
    [ 987.61 ,  156.63 ,  105.53 ,   51.1  ,    0 ],
    [1003.74 ,  151.31 ,  104.435,   52.86 ,    0 ],
    [ 968.   ,  153.41 ,  106.24 ,   58.98 ,    0 ],
    [ 978.66 ,  152.19 ,  103.28 ,   57.97 ,    0 ],
    [1001.9  ,  152.88 ,  105.08 ,   58.01 ,    0 ],
    [1024.93 ,  146.59 ,  107.06 ,   59.94 ,    0 ],
    [1020.01 ,  148.05 ,  109.96 ,   58.67 ,    0 ],
    [1034.01 ,  152.69 ,  107.64 ,   59.74 ,    0 ],
    [   0.   ,  154.88 ,  102.   ,   58.96 ,    0 ],
    [   0.   ,  147.46 ,  100.69 ,   54.95 ,    0 ],
    [   0.   ,  149.7  ,  102.439,   53.91 ,    0 ]]
)
```

I would like the fill in the zeros in the first column with the previous last value (1034.01) however if the 0's start from index 0, for it to remain as 0.

Example of end result:

```
myArrayEnd = np.array(
    [[ 976.77 ,  152.95 ,  105.62 ,   53.44 ,   0 ],
    [ 987.61 ,  156.63 ,  105.53 ,   51.1  ,    0 ],
    [1003.74 ,  151.31 ,  104.435,   52.86 ,    0 ],
    [ 968.   ,  153.41 ,  106.24 ,   58.98 ,    0 ],
    [ 978.66 ,  152.19 ,  103.28 ,   57.97 ,    0 ],
    [1001.9  ,  152.88 ,  105.08 ,   58.01 ,    0 ],
    [1024.93 ,  146.59 ,  107.06 ,   59.94 ,    0 ],
    [1020.01 ,  148.05 ,  109.96 ,   58.67 ,    0 ],
    [1034.01 ,  152.69 ,  107.64 ,   59.74 ,    0 ],
    [1034.01 ,  154.88 ,  102.   ,   58.96 ,    0 ],
    [1034.01 ,  147.46 ,  100.69 ,   54.95 ,    0 ],
    [1034.01 ,  149.7  ,  102.439,   53.91 ,    0 ]]
)
```

I would like the code to be applicable to any array not just this one, where the situation may be different. (Column 3 might be all 0's and Column 4 might have 0's in the middle which should be filled with the last previous value).

Comment: Will the 0s only exist at the end of a column or that 0s could exist in the middle of a column? Will there be cases like [1, 0, 1] for a column? If so, should the result be [1, 1, 1] or just [1, 0, 1]?

Comment: @Tai yes there will be arrays in my actual code where cases like [1, 0, 1] would exist

Comment: What should be the desired output of a [1, 0, 1] column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a vectorised way with `pandas`. This is also possible with `numpy`. In any case, you should not need explicit loops for this task.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(myArray)\
       .replace(0, np.nan)\
       .ffill().fillna(0)

res = df.values

print(res)

[[  976.77    152.95    105.62     53.44      0.   ]
 [  987.61    156.63    105.53     51.1       0.   ]
 [ 1003.74    151.31    104.435    52.86      0.   ]
 [  968.      153.41    106.24     58.98      0.   ]
 [  978.66    152.19    103.28     57.97      0.   ]
 [ 1001.9     152.88    105.08     58.01      0.   ]
 [ 1024.93    146.59    107.06     59.94      0.   ]
 [ 1020.01    148.05    109.96     58.67      0.   ]
 [ 1034.01    152.69    107.64     59.74      0.   ]
 [ 1034.01    154.88    102.       58.96      0.   ]
 [ 1034.01    147.46    100.69     54.95      0.   ]
 [ 1034.01    149.7     102.439    53.91      0.   ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Staying within `numpy`:

```
for k, c in enumerate(myArray.T):
    idx = np.flatnonzero(c == 0)
    if idx.size > 0 and idx[0] > 0:
        myArray[idx, k] = myArray[idx[0] - 1, k]
```

Comment: Nice solution if you want to stick with `numpy`. Worth commenting these loopy operations can be optimised with `numba`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've understood you correctly, this should do the trick:

```
def fill_zeroes(array):
    temp_array = array
    for i in xrange(1, len(temp_array)):
        if temp_array[i][0] == 0:
            temp_array[i][0] = temp_array[i-1][0]
    return temp_array
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this (in psuedo code)?

```
for each col in array
    for each row in col
        if array[col,row] == 0 && row>0
            array[col,row] = array[col,row-1]
```

**edit:** Combined with @ukemi, who has a quicker solution, but does not loop over the various columns. Also, you need to make sure to not try to index array[0][-1].

Answer (score 0):

The code below requires testing:

```
values = myArray.to_list()    # don't remember if nd_array.to_list is a method or property
result = []
last = None
for i,item in enumerate(values):
    if i == 0 and item[0] == 0:
        last = item
    elif item[0] == 0 and last is not None:
        item[0] = last
    else:
        last = item[0]

    result.append(item)
```